# Update DEM based on line feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem

I have a DEM which I like to update with a line feature to get some kind of line extrusion. Every cell of the dem overlapped by the line feature should have for example +10 added to it's raster value. Which tool could I use here in QGIS?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [r.carve](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjnib7mg-b3AhVR6RoKHbmiDwoQFnoECA8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgrass.osgeo.org%2Fgrass78%2Fmanuals%2Fr.carve.html&usg=AOvVaw0YqjByMpn-xCoy7zCQD1IM) within QGIS and set up a negative stream depth to increase the height of your DEM along your line feature

(In the image below a positive stream depth have been applied to the DTM)

[image]